# Movement algorithm with friction

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, physics, spring-annotations

For example, I have an object that follows mouse horizontally, its minimum position is 100 and the maximum is 200.

Within this range, it follows mouse linearly, meaning 1 unit of mouse position equals to 1 unit of object position.

Now, if the mouse is outside of the range (below 100, or above 200), I want it to start applying friction, so the object gracefully stops the further it is from range, for example:

```
Mouse position  | Object position
200               200
220               205
240               209
260               212
280               215
300               217
320               218
340               219
360               220
380               220
400               220
...
```

I managed to implement it like this within mouse-move handler:

```
if (mousePosition > 200 || mousePosition < 100) {
  delta = mousePosition - objectPosition;
  objectPosition += delta * 0.25; // 0.25 if friction factor
}
```

But is there a better way? How to implement function outside of mouse-move handler:

```
getObjectPosition(mousePosition) {
  return // ???
}
```

The question is language agnostic.

Comment: What do you mean by `better`? What is in this solution that doesn't work for your case?

Comment: @ChatterOne I'm not sure if my solution is correct, and I don't know how to answer question "What is object position if mouse position is X" without adjusting it each mouse-move frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate your the object position as a piecewise function of the mouse position:

```
getObjectPosition(mousePosition) {
    if(mousePosition < 100)
        return 100 - friction(100 - mousePosition);
    if(mousePosition > 200)
        return 200 + friction(mousePosition - 200);
    return mousePosition;
}
```

Where `friction` is a function to calculate the "soft" function you want. A simple one would be:

```
friction(x) {
    return 0.25*x;
}
```

which would reduce the object speed by 0.25 when its beyond the [100, 200] bounds. Your function seems to approach some kind of asymptote though. You can achieve it with, for example, a quadratic:

```
friction(x) {
    M = 160;
    x = min(x, M);
    return x*(1 - x/(2*M));
}
```

Here the object will gradually slow down, and stop completely when the mouse is outside the [-60, 360] interval.